# Is $\lim \space (n \sin n)= +\infty$ , or $\lim \space (n \sin n)= -\infty$ , or none of these?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is the sequence $(n\sin n)$ properly divergent i.e. do we have $\lim \space (n \sin n)= +\infty$ , or $\lim \space (n \sin  n)= -\infty$ ? ( I think the answer is know because $(n)$ is increasing unbounded but $(\sin  n)$ is bounded and divergent i.e. oscillating , but that is just a justification not a proof , I would really appreciate a rigorous proof )

Comment: For natural numbers $n$, the answer is equivalent to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665776/convergence-of-the-sequence-frac1n-sinn

Comment: Hint: Every interval of the form $((2k+1)\pi/2-1/2,(2k+1)\pi/2+1/2)$ contains an integer. From this, you can find a subsequence that converges to $\infty$ and a subsequence that converges to  $-\infty$.

Comment: Was the limit indented over the natural numbers?

Comment: @Fabian:- Yes , I said sequence , have seen your answer , great!

Comment: My answer does not apply immediately to the sequence.

Comment: @Fabian: I know because $2k\pi +\pi /2$ is not a natural number.

Comment: Yes, but I have edited it.

Answer (score 7):

Set $f(x) =  x \sin x$. You find that with $k\in \mathbb{N}$
$$ f(2k \pi+ \pi/2)   \geq k$$
and
$$ f( 2k \pi - \pi/2) \leq -k.$$

Thus $\limsup_{x\to\infty} f =\infty$ and $\liminf_{x\to\infty} f= -\infty$ and the limit does not exist.

**Edit:**

The above answer was for the limit over the real numbers. The OP asks for the limit of the sequence $f(n) = n \sin n$. We can proceed very similar.

We have to observe that for $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we have the inequalities
$$ f(x) \geq k \text{ for } x \in [2 \pi k + \pi/4, 2 \pi k + 3\pi/4],$$
$$ f(x) \leq -k \text{ for } x \in [2 \pi k- 3\pi/4, 2 \pi k  - \pi/4].$$
Furthermore, there is always an integer in the intervals which are of length $\pi/2 \geq 1.5$. Thus, we can again conclude the same thing about limsup and liminf as above.

Comment: An alternative approach with the same conclusion would be to say that since $\sin(\pm 1) \approx \pm 0.841$ and $\sin(\pm 2) \approx \pm 0.909$, in every $7(\gt 2 \pi)$ terms starting from the $n$th, there will be at least one larger than $0.841 n$ and at least one smaller than $-0.841 n$.