# Sequences unbounded above diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Prove or disprove (with counterexample) the following statement:
>
> If $a_n > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not bounded from above, then $a_n \to \infty$.

I thought the answer was true, since if the sequence is unbounded from above, and $a_n$ is greater than $0$, then it'd constantly increast to infinity. But it looks like the answer is false, and I don't really see why. What's a counterexample that refutes this statement? Thank you.

Comment: Basically, all you can say is that there exists a *subsequence* diverging to $\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about $a_{1}=1$, $a_{2}=2$, $a_{3}=1$, $a_{4}=4$, $a_{5}=1$, $a_{6}=6$, ...?

Comment: Why doesn't that converge to $\infty$? Isn't it increasing with no bound?

Comment: Assume it were, then for $M:=2$, there is some $n_{0}$ such that $a_{n}>M$ for all $n\geq n_{0}$. Now put $n=2n_{0}+1>n_{0}$ and we have $a_{n}=1$ for this $n$, but it has to be $a_{n}>2$, a contradiction.

Comment: @Max It's not increasing for example $1 = a_5 < a_4 = 4$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\;n \cdot \sin(n)\;$ for example.  See [Is $\lim \space (n \sin n)= +\infty$ , or $\lim \space (n \sin n)= -\infty$ , or none of these?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666015/is-lim-space-n-sin-n-infty-or-lim-space-n-sin-n-infty-or) for divergence, and [Is $n \sin n$ dense on the real line?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221018/is-n-sin-n-dense-on-the-real-line) for further insight.

Comment: This is not positive, but $n\lvert \sin n \rvert$ will do.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence $a_n=n(1+(-1)^n)$ which oscillates unboundedly,but $a_n$ does not tend to $\infty$.