# Why this :$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n\sin n}$ is not harmonic series and is convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I'm confused how this series :$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n\sin n}$$ is a convergent series as wolfram show [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%5Cfrac1%7Bn%5Csin+n%7D+,+n%3D1+to+infty+&wal=header) and it's not harmonic series in the same time .

**My question here is:**

Why this :$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n\sin n}$$ is not harmonic series and is convergent ?

Comment: The harmonic series is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$$ and it diverges!

Comment: This series is very different than the harmonic series, notice that the series of your question have infinite negative terms.

Comment: The series $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\sin n}$$ doesn't converge, its terms don't converge to $0$.

Comment: @Peter I don't know, when I open the link, I get a plot of the first few partial sums and "computation time exceeded", it neither says it does nor it does not converge.

Comment: I think that the claim that the terms do not converge to $0$ is wrong. Isn't $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n\sin(n)}=0$$ ?

Comment: @DanielFischer WA is wrong a lot in some basic things, but I don't think this time it is that simple: the sequence does converge to zero, I think, as for any $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ we can "squeeze" the general term between $\;-\frac1n\;$ and $\;\frac1n\;$

Comment: no the limit is not 0 because sin (n) hasn't a limt at infty

Comment: If $\frac{p}{q}$ is a convergent of $\pi$, then $$\biggl\lvert \pi - \frac{p}{q}\biggr\rvert < \frac{1}{q^2}.$$ Then $\lvert q\pi - p\rvert < \frac{1}{q}$ and hence $\lvert \sin p\rvert < \frac{1}{q} \approx \frac{\pi}{p}$. So for infinitely many $p$ (the numerators of the convergents of $\pi$ we have $\lvert p\sin p\rvert < 4$.

Comment: @user51189 That doesn't *necessarily* matter as it is bounded in $\;[-1,1]\;$

Comment: @Peter, the limit is not zero and dosn't exist because sin(n) is periodic, look here :https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%281%2F%28n+sin+n%29+,n+to+infty

Comment: @user51189 Consider that we only have the natural numbers here, not the real numbers. So, $\sin(n)\ne 0$. I think, Wolfram assumes real numbers.

Comment: @user51189 That still is wrong: the limit of $\;\frac1n\sin n\;$ is zero and **still**  sine is periodic. The reasons you give are irrelevant for the existence of the limit and its value.

Comment: ok, do u know why in ur case, because in numertor is correct because u can calculating it using variable change y=1/n and u will get siny/y y to zero , but in the latter case u can't since its multiplied by n in denomunator and no standard method exist for indterminate case to be vanish

Comment: @user51189 Since $\sin(n)$ is never $0$ for natural $n\ge 1$, we do not have an indeterminate case. So, the argument is not valid here. What might be the case : $\sin(n)$ is infinite many often so near to $0$ that the limit does not exist.

Comment: Could it be undecideable whether the sequence converges (or which limit it has ) ?

Comment: @Peter, the sequence is not bounded, so it cannot converge. Observe that $\sin n$ can be arbitrarily small frequently. We can try to prove that frequently exists some $n$ such that $(n \sin n)^{-1}>1$

Comment: @Masacroso It must be small relative to $\frac{1}{n}$ , so we cannot conclude easily that the limit does not exist. $n$ makes a "battle" against $\ \sin(n)\ $ and it is not clear who "wins" in the long term.

Comment: @Peter We can easily show that $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} \lvert n\sin n\rvert \leqslant \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{5}}$. On the other hand, clearly $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} \lvert n\sin n\rvert = +\infty$. If the [irrationality measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure) of $\pi$ is strictly greater than $2$, we have $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} \lvert n\sin n\rvert = 0$. We even have that if the irrationality measure of $\pi$ is exactly $2$ and the sequence of partial quotients is unbounded. It is very likely that it is unbounded.

Comment: See the first answer [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24579/convergence-of-sumn3-sin2n-1) for an in depth discussion on the behavior of $ | n \sin n | $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Hint:** According to the answer by @J.R. given at *[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665776/convergence-of-the-sequence-frac1n-sinn)* the sequence
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(\frac{1}{n\sin n}\right)_{n\geq 1}
> \end{align*}
>   is not convergent. We conclude  the series
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n\sin n}
> \end{align*}
>   is divergent.